# How do I update existing Jenkins jobs with a new managed Maven settings.xml file?

Tags: jenkins

I have around a hundred Maven jobs in Jenkins. I need to update them to use a new settings.xml file. I started with one job to see what it takes, but I cant seem to figure it out.

I have tried setting the File value in the Provide Configuration files section of Build Environment. This had no effect. When I run the job I still see it using the old file in the console output.

I logged into the Jenkins master and found the configuration file for the Job. Its an xml file and in it there is this section:

```
<globalSettings class="org.jenkinsci.plugins.configfiles.maven.job.MvnGlobalSettingsProvider" plugin="config-file-provider@3.7.0">
    <settingsConfigId>global-maven-settings</settingsConfigId>
</globalSettings>
```

I changed it to global-maven-settings from the ID of the old file. But, when I run the job its still using the old file.

What is the correct procedure to update all my jobs to use a new managed file?

Comment: Would it not have been easier to just update the content of the existing managed file? Otherwise you'd best use a groovy script.

Comment: Yes, but I also want to change the file-id to something more useful than 1a4e39cc-eacf-4bd0-af47-337f536fd2bd